# Insert checkboxes values(name) into input with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, symfony, checkbox

I'm working with Symfony and I have a lot of checkboxes with different id and value, so when I check one, i want to automatically insert its value (name) into an input and when I check other insert its value in the same input:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="{{ent.username}}" value="{{ent.username}}">
```

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

That does not depend on Symphony.

jQuery:

```
$(function() { // when page loads
  $("input[type='checkbox']").on("click",function() {
    if (this.checked) $("#somefield").val(this.value);
  });
});
```

Plain JS:

```
window.onload=function() { // when page loads
  document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']").forEach(function() {
    this.onclick=function() {
      if (this.checked) document.getElementById("somefield").value=this.value;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps to follow:

- Add change listener on each `input` field of `checkbox` type.
- Get all the selected fruit by iterating each checkbox.
- Set the value of selected fruits in the field.

Running sample code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
 <input type="checkbox" value="Banana">Banana</input> 
 <input type="checkbox" value="Apple">Apple</input> 
 <input type="checkbox" value="Mangeo">Mango</input> 
 <input type="checkbox" value="Orange">Orange</input> 
</div>

<div>
  Selected Fruit : <input type="text" id="fruit">
</div>


<script>
  
  var fruit = $('#fruit');
  
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(e){
     fruit.val(getSelectedFruits());
  });

  function getSelectedFruits(){
   var fruits = "";
   $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(i,cb){
       if($(this).is(":checked")){
           fruits += $(this).val() + " ";
       }
   });
   return fruits;
  }
  
</script>
```